# Cannot show the data on browser by using ajax ,spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: html, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The data taken by ajax cannot show in the html.
The result just show the data on the browser below

[{"id":1,"description":"ゲームの世界に入ったかのような感覚をさらに高める","price":10000.0,"stock":5,"status":1,"productName":"PlayStation VR"}]

I cannot solve the problem although I have tried to find it out for two days.
Would someone please give me a helping hand?

I confirmed that the data are successfully gotten from the db.
I checked the method and both thymeleaf  and ajax side are using get method. The path of the html file is in templates folder . The other html without ajax are properly work  and shown in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<script src="C:\Shopping-site\src\main\resources\static\js\products.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/products}" method="get">
   <ul id="productList">
   <li th:each="product : ${products}">
           <h2 th:text="'产品名称: ' + ${product.productName}"></h2>
           <p th:text="'价格: ' + ${product.price}"></p>
           <p th:text="'价格: ' + ${product.status}"></p>
   </li>
 </ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
fetch('/products', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Request fail');
  }
  return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  
  console.log(data);

  const products = data;

  const productList = document.getElementById('productList');

  products.forEach(product => {
 
    const productElement = document.createElement('li');
    productElement.textContent = `Product Name: ${product.productName}, Price: ${product.price}, Status: ${product.status}`;
    productList.appendChild(productElement);
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

```
package com.Shoppingsite.Shoppingsite.controller;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int stock;
    private int status;

    // 构造函数

    // Getter和Setter方法
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productname) {
        this.productName = productname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    // 可以添加其他方法或构造函数根据需要
}
package com.Shoppingsite.Shoppingsite.controller;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int stock;
    private int status;

    // 构造函数

    // Getter和Setter方法
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productname) {
        this.productName = productname;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```